# Circle - Canvas get pixel color of lineWidth

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I would like to get pixel color of a `lineWidth` circle. I have tested a lot of solution but never return the `Linewidth` color.

Below an example i tried:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth=3;
ctx.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();

function findPos(obj) {
    var curleft = 0, curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
        return { x: curleft, y: curtop };
    }
    return undefined;
}

function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
    if (r > 255 || g > 255 || b > 255)
        throw "Invalid color component";
    return ((r << 16) | (g << 8) | b).toString(16);
}



$('#myCanvas').mousemove(function(e) {
    var pos = findPos(this);
    var x = e.pageX - pos.x;
    var y = e.pageY - pos.y;
    var coord = "x=" + x + ", y=" + y;
    var c = this.getContext('2d');
    var p = c.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data; 
    var hex = "#" + ("000000" + rgbToHex(p[0], p[1], p[2])).slice(-6);
    $('#status').html(coord + "<br>" + hex);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas  id="myCanvas" width="300" height="200" ></canvas>
<div id="status"></div>
```

Original jsfiddle i took as example with square color : http://jsfiddle.net/DV9Bw/1/

Another jsfiddle i tried : http://jsfiddle.net/9SEMf/1727/

Comment: You are not going to find the colour because you are looking for black on a transparent canvas. That means all pixels are black, just the ones you have drawn also have the alpha value set. Try using a different colour to draw your circle

Comment: Ok, is perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually there is nothing wrong with your code. The reason why the color hex value doesn't change is because the canvas default background looks white but it is actually black with 0 alpha.

If you print the value inside your mousemove handler like
`console.log(JSON.stringify(p));` while the mouse is not over the circle, you will see something like: `{"0":0,"1":0,"2":0,"3":0}`.

Notice the forth value for the alpha.

You could fill the canvas with white before drawing the circle to see the difference.

```
//fill the entier canvas with opaque white
ctx.rect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
ctx.fill();
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f5m3vdpd/1/) with your example

Comment: Thank you is exaclty what i want!